# Config File without Environment Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I don't have permission to create the Environment variable and I want to pass my Config file path and Name using variable.

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit? a) What is the config file (is it a dtsconfig for an SSIS package?) and b) where do you want to pass its location from/to?

Comment: You may not have permission to create a system-level environment variable, but do you have permission to create a user-level variable?

Comment: @DeanOC - a) yes its a .dtsconfig file for the SSIS Pkg b) I pass the loaction on my server drive (D:) folder. and I also placed my .dtsx file at the same location but on different folder.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - true...I dont have a permission to create the Environment var but I do have permission for the Temp User variable.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use one of the other configuration methods (SQL Server or XML)? Since you have file access, using XML seems appropriate.

See the section for "Types of Configurations":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx